# How to add placeholder on input in Symfony 4 form?

Tags: html, symfony4

In my Symfony 4 form, I am try to get a placeholder for my input. I tried the below but I get an error that it is not allowed. Any ideas how else I can achieve this?

```html
        ->add('firstname', TextType::class, ['label' => 'Vorname ', 'placeholder' => 'Your name',])
```

As suggested in the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#attr) I have also tried the below, here I am not getting an error, just nothing is rendering.

```html
        ->add('firstname', TextType::class, ['label' => 'Vorname '], ['attr' => ['placeholder' => 'Vorname ']])
```

Comment: [`empty_data`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#empty-data)?

Comment: @BenM didn't work but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Something wrong with my answer ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to do like this :

```
->add('firstname', TextType::class, array(
      'label' => 'Vorname ',
      'attr' => array(
          'placeholder' => 'hereYourPlaceHolder'
      )
 ))
```

As they say in the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#attr)

Comment: Albeit different syntax, I have tried what they have suggested but still nothing! This is what I tried:         ->add('firstname', TextType::class, ['label' => 'Vorname '], ['attr' => ['placeholder' => 'Vorname ']])

Comment: There is no 'placeholder' option in TextType... Take a look about my answer.

Comment: Or you can use like this directly in the Twig : {{ form_widget (form.firstname.first, {'attr': {'placeholder': 'Vorname '}}) }}

Comment: Strangely, this doesn't work for me in Symfony 4.4. I have had to resort to @kontenurban 's answer below and pass through the placeholder in the Twig template. For the life of me I can't see why I have to do this because the answer here makes sense to me and aligns with the documentation. Strange one.

Answer (score 2):

This also works, by rendering the items individually and adding an attribute in the twig!

```html
{{ form_label(form.firstname) }}
{{ form_widget(form.firstname, {'attr': {'placeholder': 'FIRSTNAME'}}) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of Symfony 6 suggests two ways.

The first option is inside the `yourForm.php`:

```
->add('name', TextType::class,
    [
        'label'    => 'Name *',
        'attr' => ['placeholder' => 'Name *'],
        'required' => true
    ])
```

The second option is inside the `twig template`:

```
{{ form_label(form.name) }}
{{ form_widget(form.name, {'attr': {'placeholder': 'Name*' }}) }}
```

You can find more information in the official documentation of [Symfony 6 FormType](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is worked in Symfony 4

```
            ->add('fullName', null, [
                'label' => 'Kontaktperson',
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Contact person name'
                ],
            ])
```

More details: http://toihid.com/?p=326

Comment: Hey, Khandaker. Can you please type up the "more details part" in your answer?